# Regex to validate domain not ending with period, instead end with character or digit (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using below regex for email address validation. Issue is if the domain part (that is after `@`) is ending with dot(`.`) it is considering it as valid address instead of failing it.

```
regex = /^((?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x20\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(\[(?:[:0-9A-Za-z]+)\])|(?:[:0-9A-Za-z]+)))/;
```

Below are few emails of which are allowed and not allowed. Please suggest.

```
sample@exam - valid,
sample@exam.com - valid,
sample@exam.com.in - valid,
sample@.exam - invalid,
sample@exam. - invalid,
```

Comment: Please, format the text properly, it is painful to watch at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Try [\S+@(?:\w+$|\w+\.\w+\.?\w+$)](https://regex101.com/r/Fkpfpt/3)